# How to add inbox notification system and delete message from one user django channels

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am trying to build a messenger like application using Django, Django-rest-framework, and Django-channels.
Right now I can only send messages from one user to another user. But I want to add features like, new messages will be on top in the inbox along with the username and one user can delete messages from his side, just like messenger, whats app, etc. When someone sends a message his message will be on top and will show a notification.
I am unable to find out perfect model design and perfect system for doing it.

Model.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='sender_messages')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='receiver_messages')
    text = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} to {}'.format(self.sender.name, self.receiver.name)
```

consumer

```py
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

from .models import Message

User = get_user_model()


class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        """
        Join channel group by chatname.
        """
        self.group_name = 'chat_{0}'.format(self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['chatname'])

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        """
        Leave channel by group name.
        """
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        """
        Receive message from websocket and send message to channel group.
        """
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        name = text_data_json['name']
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Store message.
        receiver = User.objects.get(
            name=self.group_name.replace('chat_', '')
                .replace(self.scope['user'].name, '')
                .replace('-', ''))
        Message(sender=self.scope['user'], receiver=receiver, text=message).save()

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'name': name,
                'message': message,
            }
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        """
        Receive message from channel group and send message to websocket.
        """
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'name': event['name'],
            'message': event['message'],
        }))
```

view

```py
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # List all users for chatting. Except myself.

        context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(id=self.request.user.id) \
            .values('name')
        context['users'] = User.objects.exclude(gender=self.request.user.gender)
        return context


class ChatHomeApi(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = InboxRetrieveSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    pagination_class = GeneralPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Chat_Inbox.objects.filter(sender=self.request.user)


class ChatView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'chat.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Get the person we are chatting with, if not exist raise 404.
        receiver_name = kwargs['chatname'].replace(
            request.user.name, '').replace('-', '')
        kwargs['receiver'] = get_object_or_404(User, name=receiver_name)
        return super().dispatch(request, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['receiver'] = kwargs['receiver']
        return context


class MessagesAPIView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, chatname):
        # Grab two users based on the chat name.
        users = User.objects.filter(name__in=chatname.split('-'))
        # Filters messages between this two users.
        result = Message.objects.filter(
            Q(sender=users[0], receiver=users[1]) | Q(sender=users[1], receiver=users[0])
        ).annotate(
            name=F('sender__name'), message=F('text'),
        ).order_by('date_created').values('name', 'message', 'date_created')

        return JsonResponse(list(result), safe=False)
```

So basically, I want to show new messages on top of the inbox, and a user can delete messages from his side, and this might not affect the other user.
Thanks in advance

Comment: One way to implement the one-sided delete is to have 2 message objects for every message - one for the sender, the other for the receiver. Each user can delete their own message object and it won't affect the other user

Comment: Thought of that for the model, but how will I send data to the websocket/frontend if someone messages a user?

Comment: Please refer to the Django channel docs on how to send message to the connected clients. As for ordering the messages, you can use the timestamp of when the message was sent to order it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ordering, you can send the time stamp along with all messages and store that timestamp.

Now at the time of retrieving the messages, you can retrieve them by using `order_by` in Django.

for e.g.,

```
def receive(self, text_data): 
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    name = text_data_json['name']
    message = text_data_json['message']
    timestamp = timezone.now()
    # Store message.
    receiver = User.objects.get(
        name=self.group_name.replace('chat_', '')
            .replace(self.scope['user'].name, '')
            .replace('-', ''))
    Message(sender=self.scope['user'], receiver=receiver, text=message).save()

    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
        self.group_name,
        {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'name': name,
            'message': message,
            'timestamp': timestamp.isoformat()
        }
    )


async def chat_message(self, event):
    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': 'Message Received Successfully',
        'data': {
            'message': event['message'],
            'message_type': event['message_type'],
            'timestamp': event['timestamp']
        }
    }))
```